# Android threads and timer slow down running when lockscreen

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, background, lockscreen

First sorry for my english.
I have a problem, and i can't find a solution, it sounds like: 
i'm developping an app that's getting my location from gps and send it to a tcp server on pc , and store the data into a listview (for example). I have set a timer that send the location every 2 seconds. Everything works fine even if i connect two clients to server, until the phones gets locked .. then my server receive ugly string ..it seems like the sent-strings it straddles (the string contains parts of data from bought clients, parts are concatenated) .. but when i unlock the phones the server receive normal strings again..
        I want to know how to make my app run in the same parameters when lock screen occurs .. Any ideas?

Comment: i override onPuase ..and make it to do nothing that should mean that my app continue running.. but it not.. or i'm worng? but i don't think that's the problem because if i press the home button my app run perfectly until the phone is locked

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this inside an activity or a fragment you are probably having an issue with the lifecycle of your app. If you want to understand the lifecycle, read this documentation article: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Doing nothing on your onPause method won't prevent your activity from sleeping, Android can kill your activity anytime.

The proper way to do this would be inside a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), a service is a special component on Android that is executed independently of what the user is doing or not doing, and in this case, you could create a service that holds a wake lock in order to prevent it from sleeping for the couple of seconds you need to send your data.

An easier solution would be to use something like this [Location polling library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) and suit it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

When the screen locks your activity is either paused on stopped and it is important you handle these methods so that any interuptions are handled elegantly and without error. Or so the app will continue to run in the background.

If you read up about the [activity lifecycle.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

> During normal app use, the foreground activity is sometimes obstructed by other visual components that cause the activity to pause. For example, when a semi-transparent activity opens (such as one in the style of a dialog), the previous activity pauses. As long as the activity is still partially visible but currently not the activity in focus, it remains paused.
>
> However, once the activity is fully-obstructed and not visible, it stops (which is discussed in the next lesson).

[image: Activity Lifecycle from Android com]
Activity Lifecycle from android.com